# Is quadratic residuosity problem in coNP?

Tags: computational-complexity, quadratic-reciprocity

Quadratic residuosity is in $\mathsf{NP}$, since to prove $x$ is quadratic residue you can show $y$ such that $y^2=x$.

Wikipedia [claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof#History_and_results) the problem is in $\mathsf{coNP}$. [This](http://books.google.com/books?id=y_ZwupY8pzUC&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234) book claims it is not known. Is it?

It seems at:

- When $n$ is prime, one can use [Euler's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_criterion) so the problem is in $\mathsf{P}$,
- In general case one can give factorization of $n$ and reduce the problem to $n=p^k$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Seems you are right to me.  Note that verifying a prime factorization consists of not only verifying that the product is $n$, but also verifying that the claimed factors are indeed prime.  But this can be done in polynomial time.

Comment: Although you posted this many years ago, it has some problems. First of all the problem that you talk about in Wikipedia is not quadratic reciprocity, but quadratic residuosity. Finding out whether a number is a quadratic residue would then be quadratic residuosity. Might you change the title of your post? There are also some intruiguing questions related to the answer you have accepted.

Comment: @EGME I've changed the post, thank you for the insights.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are correct.

First of all, the prover can provide the prime factorization of $n$, so without loss of generality assume $n = p^k$ for some $k$. We have thus reduced the problem to the prime powers.

I am taking the following sets of rules for determining if a number is a quadratic residue or not modulo $p^k$ from [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_power_modulus). Be careful in reading the wikipedia page since it uses a different notation than in the question.

> If the modulus is $p^k$, then $p^x A$
>
> - is a residue modulo $p^k$ if $x \geq k$
> - is a nonresidue modulo $p^k$ if $x < k$ is odd
> - is a residue modulo $p^k$ if $x < k$ is even and $A$ is a residue modulo $p$
> - is a nonresidue modulo $p^k$ if $x < k$ is even and $A$ is a nonresidue modulo $p$.

And for $p=2$:

> All odd squares are $\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ and a fortiori $\equiv 1 \pmod 4$. If $a$ is an odd number and $m = 8, 16$, or some higher power of $2$, then $a$ is a residue modulo $m$ if and only if $a \equiv 1 \pmod 8$.
>
> So a nonzero number is a residue modulo $8, 16$, etc., if and only if it is of the form $4^x(8y + 1)$.

So we are finally reduced to the case of checking whether a given number is a quadratic residue or nonresidue modulo a prime $p$. But as the OP notes, that can be easily done in deterministic polynomial time using Euler's criterion.

Answer (score 2):

Quadratic residuosity is in NP$\cap$co-NP, see Corollary 10 in the following article by Cai and Threlfall:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019004001991

What is in the book linked is a mistake. The same mistake appears in Arora and Barak’s text, in example 8.9 (personal communication with one of the authors).